# Solving an ODE with parameters and taking the limit of the solution

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I am very new to Mathematica and already spent a lot of time trying to do this but failed.

I am trying to solve an ODE:

```
solution = DSolve[{-((m (1 + m) + 4/(9 (-2/3 + t) t)) y[t]) + 
     2 (-1/3 + t) y'[t] + (-2/3 + t) t y''[
       t] == (-4 (1 + C/2))/(9 (-2/3 + t) t), y[1] == 1, y'[1] == C}, 
  y, t]
```

where $m$ is a nonnegative integer and $C$ is a real number.

I want to show that there exists a $C$ such that the solution is $0$ at infinity.
When I try that code:

```
Limit[y[t] /. solution[[1]], t -> Infinity, m \[Element] Integers]
```

it just spits out the same thing.

What should I do?
(Note that I don't need to find that value of $C$; I just need to show that for every $m$, there is a number $C$ in which the solution vanishes at infinity. )

EDIT:

I amanged to get that it's true for many values of $m$. Here is the code I used for $m=10$.

```
solutionm = 
 DSolve[{-((10 (10 + 1) + 4/(9 (-2/3 + t) t)) y[t]) + 
     2 (-1/3 + t) y'[t] + (-2/3 + t) t y''[
       t] == (-4 (1 + C/2))/(9 (-2/3 + t) t), y[1] == 1, y'[1] == C}, 
  y, t]
```

```
Limit[FullSimplify[Re[y[t] /. solutionm[[1]]]], t -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> C \[Element] Reals]
```

Which spits out:

```
DirectedInfinity[360 (1036 - 943 Log[3]) + C (-59572 + 54225 Log[3])]
```

Then I choose the $C$ that makes that number in "DirectedInfinity" zero:

```
{a} = Solve[360 (1036 - 943 Log[3]) + C (-59572 + 54225 Log[3]) == 0, 
  C]
a = C /. a[[1]]
```

Then when $C=a$, the limit is 0:

```
Limit[Re[y[t] /. solutionm[[1]]], t -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> C == a]
0
```

I tried for many values of $m$, and I get the same thing. When I try to make $m$ arbitrary, something weird happens:

```
$Assumptions={m \[Element] Integers, C \[Element] Reals}
solutionm = 
 DSolve[{-((m (m + 1) + 4/(9 (-2/3 + t) t)) y[t]) + 
     2 (-1/3 + t) y'[t] + (-2/3 + t) t y''[
       t] == (-4 (1 + C/2))/(9 (-2/3 + t) t), y[1] == 1, y'[1] == C}, 
  y, t]
```

When I run `y[t] /. solutionm[[1]] /. {m -> 1}`, it gives me an error: `Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.` I get the same error with any $m$. I am not sure why this happens.

Also, when I repeat the same thing as above, and run

```
Limit[FullSimplify[Re[y[t] /. solutionm[[1]]]], t -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> C \[Element] Reals]
```

it doesn't compute the limit. It just spits out the same thing. Is there a way around this? Or, as Nasser suggested, is this too complicated for Mathematica?
Also, I don't need to find that $C$. I just want to show that there exists a $C$ in which the solution vanishes at infinity.

Comment: better not to use `C`. use lower case `c`.  But have you looked at how complicated the solution of the ODE is?  it is pages and pages of special functions and integrals as well inside.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdS1a.png)  Mathematica is not a magic box although many think it is.

Comment: It's not too long when simplified. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=t%28t-2%2F3%29+y%27%27%28t%29+%2B+2%28t-1%2F3%29y%27%28t%29+-+%284%2F%289+t%28t-2%2F3%29%29+%2B+m%28m%2B1%29%29+y%28t%29+%3D+-4%2F%289t%28t-2%2F3%29%29+%281%2F2+C%2B1%29%2C+y%281%29+%3D+1%2C+y%27%281%29+%3D+C

Comment: How do I make a code to get the limit, and find if there is a C such that the limit is 0?

Comment: You could try numerical simulation, with different values and change time. Using Manipulate for example.  Using `NDSolve`. I do not think you can do this analytically. The solution to the ODE is just too complicated, even for Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer for `m==2` in version 13.1 on Windows 10 (`C` is reserved in WL.)

```
ClearAll[m, c]; $Assumptions = {m \[Element] Integers, c \[Element] Reals}; m = 2;
solution = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{-((m (m + 1) + 4/(9 (-2/3 + t) t)) y[t]) + 
  2 (-1/3 + t) y'[t] + (-2/3 + t) t y''[t] ==
 (-4 (1 + c/2))/(9 (-2/3 + t) t), y[1] == 1, y'[1] == c}, y[t], {t, Infinity, 1}];
Limit[solution, t -> Infinity]
```

> `\[Infinity] (48-36 Log[3]+c (-68+63 Log[3]))`

Now

```
Solve[(48 - 36 Log[3] + c (-68 + 63 Log[3])) == 0, c]
```

> `{{c -> (-48 + 36 Log[3])/(-68 + 63 Log[3])}}`

and then

```
ClearAll[m, c]; m = 2; c = (-48 + 36 Log[3])/(-68 + 63 Log[3]);
solution = AsymptoticDSolveValue[{-((m (m + 1) + 4/(9 (-2/3 + t) t)) y[t]) + 
  2 (-1/3 + t) y'[t] + (-2/3 + t) t y''[
    t] == (-4 (1 + c/2))/(9 (-2/3 + t) t), y[1] == 1, y'[1] == c},
y[t], {t, Infinity, 1}];
Limit[solution, t -> Infinity]
```

> `0`

A similar behavior for other natural `m` I tried. In the general case `AsymptoticDSolveValue` fails.

Answer (score 0):

We can have an insight about the solutions behavior for each `m` by doing

```
tmax = 1000;
solution = ParametricNDSolve[{-((m (1 + m) + 4/(9 (-2/3 + t) t)) y[t]) + 2 (-1/3 + t) y'[t] + (-2/3 + t) t y''[t] == (-4 (1 + c/2))/(9 (-2/3 + t) t), y[1] == 1, y'[1] == c}, y, {t, 1, tmax}, {m, c}]

m = 1;

Plot3D[Evaluate[y[m, c][t] /. solution], {t, 1, tmax}, {c, -6, 0}]
```

Comment: I want to understand the behaviour of the solution at infinity though. So numerical methods doesn't help. Also I managed to get what I want when I specify what $m$ is. But I am not sure how to proceed if I want to prove it for any m.